# Using a variable in one function to another in the same controller

Tags: php, oop

I have a variable in one function which I intend to use in the next function:

Most explanations seem to have the variable defined in the same function i need it called

I have a variable in one function which I intend to use in the next function:

Function 1:

```php
public function getBookingItem($empl_id){
  $BookedEmployee=Employee::where('id',$empl_id)
    ->first();
}
```

Function 2:

```php
public function postBookings(Request $request){
  //use it here 
  dd($BookedEmployee);
}
```

Also if the variable is a collection then it would be great show how to access a field in the collection

Comment: I would say this is not a Laravel specific issue, is more PHP or Object Oriented Programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set static private variable in controller and use it for your function just :

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
   private $BookedEmployee;
   public function __construct(){
       $this->middleware(HasApiToken::class);
   }

    public function getBookingItem($empl_id){
        $this->BookedEmployee =Employee::where('id',$empl_id)->first();
    }

    public function postBookings(Request $request){
     //use it here 
     dd($this->BookedEmployee);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `statis` exactly? What's the point in that?

Comment: static varible will be fix after assign

Comment: Why STATIC though??

Comment: i think static will be better beacuse 2 controller function(in routing setting) maybe not from one object!!!!

Comment: So you need to create an instance of the class and call a non-static function and pass a parameter to that function just to save the result into a static member? What is your logic? I didn't downvote, but it's for a good reason. If there is some logic behind this code then you should explain it

Comment: no there is no more reason.so You think it can be non static variable?

Comment: I know nothing about Laravel, but it seems strange that you need to call a non-static method and I don't understand why saving the result into a static member

Comment: Why not using `$this->BookedEmployee =.. ;` instead?

Comment: updated with delete static part.thank you

Comment: Oh, now this is an answer I'm happy to upvote. Good job!

Comment: this is still not working for me. its almost as though dd($this->BookedEmployee); returns nothing